# Windows 7 does not recognize filesystem on external harddisk which works on any other PC

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb

I have Windows 7 installed on a PC, and try to attach a external 2.5" Seagate 320GB harddisk. The PC itself is perfectly able to see this disk, and even boot from it on startup. There is onyl one partition on this disk, type NTFS, and it can be quickly found on any other PC in Windows.

When I boot into Windows 7 on this PC, and attach this external hard drive (remember, it's not a hardware problem, this PC is even able to boot from this disk!), it is quickly recognized by Windows, but the partition type is unknown, Windows only detects one partition that has no type or name, nor a drive letter in the Disk Management console.

The problem is persistent, tried many reboots, shudowns, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

May be in this PC USB port has no power to start HD properly. Try to connect HD using short cable or cable with 2 USB connectors.